# Cannot run long python text in VSCode

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

This is a strange problem (in VSCode) I am experiencing. I have a long multi-line text, which will neither get copied to the python terminal (Ctrl + V) from the editor nor responds to Shift-Enter shortcut. For instance this text

```
    lorem1 = """ Lorem Ipsum is slechts een proeftekst uit het drukkerij- en zetterijwezen. Lorem Ipsum is de standaard proeftekst in deze bedrijfstak sinds de 16e eeuw,
    Lorem Ipsum is slechts een proeftekst uit het drukkerij- en zetterijwezen. Lorem Ipsum is de standaard proeftekst in deze bedrijfstak sinds de 16e eeuw, 
    toen een onbekende drukker een zethaak met letters nam en ze door elkaar husselde om een font-catalogus te maken. Het heeft niet alleen vijf eeuwen zetterijwezen. 
    Lorem Ipsum is de standaard proeftekst in deze bedrijfstak elektronische letterzetting. Het is in de jaren '60 populair geworden met de introductie van Letraset vellen met 
    Lorem Ipsum passages en meer recentelijk door desktop publishing software zoals Aldus PageMaker die versies van Lorem Ipsum bevatten 
    Lorem Ipsum is slechts een proeftekst uit het drukkerij- en zetterijwezen. Lorem Ipsum is de standaard proeftekst in deze bedrijfstak sinds de 16e eeuw, 
    toen een onbekende drukker een zethaak met letters nam en ze door elkaar husselde om een font-catalogus te maken. Het heeft niet alleen vijf eeuwen zetterijwezen. 
    Lorem Ipsum is de standaard proeftekst in deze bedrijfstak elektronische letterzetting. Het is in de jaren '60 populair geworden met de introductie van Letraset vellen met .
    Lorem Ipsum passages en meer recentelijk door desktop publishing software zoals Aldus PageMaker die versies van Lorem Ipsum bevatten
    Lorem Ipsum passages en meer recentelijk door desktop publishing software zoals Aldus PageMaker die versies van Lorem Ipsum bevatten
    Lorem Ipsum passages en meer recentelijk door desktop publishing software zoals Aldus PageMaker die versies van Lorem Ipsum bevatten
Lorem Ipsum passages en meer recentelijk door desktop publishing software zoals Aldus PageMaker die versies van Lorem Ipsum bevatten
    Lorem Ipsum passages en meer recentelijk door desktop publishing software zoals Aldus PageMaker die versies van Lorem Ipsum bevatten
    Lorem Ipsum passages en meer recentelijk door desktop publishing software zoals Aldus PageMaker die versies van Lorem Ipsum bevatten"""
```

will not respond to the Shift + Enter command, but if reduce four or three lines the command works. I tested this works in IDLE, but something is off with VSCOde I guess, can you please help me?

Comment: Your example has an indent problem of not starting from column 0. After I fixed that then it worked fine for me.

Comment: sorry, what does not starting from column 0 mean? And how did you fix this?

Comment: dedent your first line so that `lorem1` is all the way to the left.